# Mosquitto: published mqtt message not delivered to websockets client

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I am running mosquitto on Windows, and configured it to work as mqtt on port 1883, and websockets on port 9001. I thought I could publish a message from an mqtt client and receive it on a websockets client, but it appears not to be so.

I can successfully deliver a message from an mqtt client to another mqtt client, as well as from a websockets client to another websockets client. All in all, there seems to be a impassable boundary between the two protocols.

Is this a limitation of Mosquitto?
Have I forgotten to set something in the conf file?

Note: I invoke Mosquitto with a -v option, so it logs verbosely. I have noticed that it actually logs connections and messages for websockets clients, but not for mqtt clients, although on mqtt client side everyting regarding connection and publishing seems ok (I am using MQTTNet client to publish, either in mqtt or in websockets mode, and PAHO javascript client, in websockets mode, for subscribing/receiving).

Disabling or enabling the firewall didn't make any difference.

Edit:
Here is the relevant section on the conf file:

```
listener 1883
protocol mqtt
listener 9001
protocol websockets
password_file mypasswordfile.pwd
```

This is what it reports when I launch it:

```
prompt> ./mosquitto -c myconfig.conf -v
2022-10-15 20:25:53: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
2022-10-15 20:25:53: Config loaded from myconfig.conf.
2022-10-15 20:25:53: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
2022-10-15 20:25:53: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
2022-10-15 20:25:53: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
2022-10-15 20:25:53: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

This is the relevant code fragment from the publisher (but I have also tried the mosquitto_pub utility):

```
var mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();
var mqttClient = mqttFactory.CreateMqttClient();
var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder().
    // WithTcpServer("localhost").                     // This does NOT work
    WithWebSocketServer("ws://localhost:9001/mqtt").   // This works
    WithProtocolVersion(MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V311).
    WithClientId("publisher-client-id").
    WithCredentials("myusername", "mypassword").
    Build();
mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions, CancellationToken.None).Wait();

var builder = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder();
var applicationMessage = builder
    .WithTopic("mytopic")
    .WithPayload("mypayload")
    .Build();
mqttClient.PublishAsync(applicationMessage, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

and here is a code fragment from the subscriber:

```
mqttConnect() {
    this._mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client('localhost', 9001, '/mqtt', 'subscriber-client-id');
    this._mqtt.onConnectionLost = this.onMqttConnectionLost.bind(this);
    this._mqtt.onMessageArrived = this.onMqttMessageReceived.bind(this);
    const options = {
        mqttVersion: 4,
        userName: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword',
        onSuccess: this.onMqttConnected.bind(this),
        onFailure: this.onMqttFailedConnecting.bind(this)
    };
    this._mqtt.connect(options);
    ...
}
onMqttConnected() {
    console.log('Connected to MQTT broker');
    ...
    this._mqtt.subscribe('mytopic');
}
onMqttMessageReceived(message) {
    console.log('Received MQTT message; topic = ' + message.destinationName + ', payload = ' + message.payloadString);
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, there is no boundary or limitiatoin. Edit the question to show, the websocket code, the publisher and the mosquitto.conf

Comment: Please do as I asked and show the config file, and the mosquitto startup output. Best guess is that you are actually running 2 versions, one on each port

Comment: @hardillb Edited! Please notice that PAHO mqtt version 4 corresponds to 3.1.1

Comment: And just to be clear, **everything** is running on the same machine?

Comment: Also have you built mosquitto yourself from src? What platform are you on?

Comment: @hardillb Yes, for the moment I'm experimenting, so it's all on localhost. Windows 8.1 PC.

Comment: @hardillb I downloaded the already-build mosquitto: mosquitto-2.0.15-install-windows-x64.exe (64-bit build, Windows Vista and up, built with Visual Studio Community 2019).
Using dotnet 6.0.203, and MQTTnet 4.1.0.247.
The browser is Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official build) (64 bit).
The PAHO mqtt javascript library is 1.0.3.

Comment: I've just tested (all be it on Windows 10) with that build and as close as I can with the code you've provided and everything works fine. (and everything is logged). Only thing I can think to check is that you are not running a copy of the broker as a service in the background (the install will do this by default)

Comment: @hardillb You are right! I can't believe it! But I wonder how the service and the "foreground" instance could both open port 1883 to listen to clients; why didn't the foreground istance issue an error message when trying to open that very same port? The OS forbids to open the same port twice, as far as I know.
Anyway, thank you so much!
Please issue your suggestions as an answer, I would be very glad to upvote it, and indicate it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As thrashed out in the comments, there were 2 instance running (one the Windows service, one in the command prompt).

Shutting down the background service fixed the problem.

(It is unclear why both instances were able to bind to port 1883)